# Linksys AE1200 usb dongle

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, usb

I have read the  How do I install the driver for my Linksys AE1200 Wireless-N USB Adapter? question and I have been able to get the blue indicator light on and

> Sudo ndiswrapper -l :
>
> bcmwlhigh5 : driver installed
>
> device (13B1:0039) present

The problem is that when I go to my networking (Wcid network manager) it does not come up at all, What whats wrong?
about my machine:

- Ubuntu 14. trusty tahr
- wireless dongle is the only way beside a Internet cable to give me Internet(were this machine needs to go a cable is not possible and it does not have a built in wifi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you choose **wlan0** as interface name and **wext** as driver in Wicd? Please check:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
sudo service wicd restart
```

Comment: yes wlan0 is the interface name and not sure about wext sorry for bieng late I had a ton of work and not enough time to work on this

Comment: this worked :) thanks a lot and for the record my driver was wext.

Answer (score -1):

I was pretty happy yesterday when I found that **Linksys AE1200** usb dongle is fully supported in elementary OS that is based on **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**. It worked flawlessly at the first boot. So to everyone asking if it will work on linux, I say yes, **it does work** in the new linux versions without hassle.